# pgfplotstable: How to use a values from a column in another column

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have

```
X Y
1 a
2 b
5 c
```

I need

```
X Y
1 a=1
2 b=2
5 c=5
```

How can I get the values of the X-column and use them in the Y-column?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\def\ImageScale{0.1}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
1 a
2 b
5 c 
}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/Y/.style={
postproc cell content/.style={
@cell content={##1 = ......}           },
},
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
X Y
1 a
2 b
5 c
}\mytable
\section{old}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}

\section{new}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
columns/Y/.style={
preproc cell content/.code={%
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\myvar%
%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\mytable
\edef\temp{%
\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\myvar=\pgfplotsretval}}%
\temp%
},
}
]\mytable
\end{document}
```